# Combine Like Terms and Coefficient of One

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I realize this is a simple question but I am having trouble understanding/remembering some specific rules relating to combining like terms:

why does:

3xy + 2xy = 5xy rather than 3xy + 2xy = 5x2y ?

since y has a coefficient of 1 shouldn't it be 
3x1y + 2x1y = 5x2y

Thank you for cleaning up this confusion

Comment: What does 5x2y mean? Is it 10xy? Is it 5x+2y?

Answer (score 1):

The constant coefficients in the terms $3xy$ and $2xy$ apply to the entire term, not just to the $x$ because they happen to be next to it: remember that $3xy$ means $3\cdot x\cdot y$.

If in doubt, plug in actual numbers for $x$ and $y$. Suppose we let $x=y=1$. Then $3xy+2xy=3\cdot1\cdot1+2\cdot1\cdot1=3+2=5$, but using your proposed solution, you would end up with $5x2y=5\cdot1\cdot2\cdot1=10$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

The distributive law states that $(a + b)c = ac + bc$.

If we set $a = 3$, $b = 2$, and $c = xy$, then $5xy = (3 + 2)xy = 3xy + 2xy$.

Answer (score 0):

You can define $z=xy,$ then $3xy+2xy=3z+2z=5z=5xy$ follows the distributive law.  Without defining $z$ you could say $3xy+2xy=(3+2)xy=5xy$ or $3xy+2xy=(3x+2x)y=5xy$

Comment: I'm more confused by what OP means by 5x2y. I think that is crucial in understanding where OP is going wrong.

Comment: @DonThousand:  I am reasonably sure it is $10xy$, but confirmation would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Recall that multiplication is associative, so an expression like $2xy$ could be expressed as either $(2x)y$ or $2(xy)$.

So
$$3xy+2xy = (3x)y+(2x)y = 3(xy) + 2(xy) = (3+2)(xy) = 5(xy) = (5x)y = 5xy$$